# Finding examples of root systems

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $\mathbb{E} \cong \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector space with an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. A subset $R \subset \mathbb{E} \setminus \{0\}$ is called a root system, if $R$ has the following properties

1. $R$ is finite and spans $\mathbb{E}$
2. if $\alpha \in R$ then $-\alpha \in R$ and $\pm \alpha$ are the only multiples of $\alpha$ in $R$
3. R is invariant under the reflection in the hyperplane orthogonal to any $\alpha \in R$, i.e, $\forall_{\alpha, \beta} \in R, \; s_\alpha(\beta) = \beta - 2\operatorname{proj}_\alpha(\beta) \in R$
4. $\forall \alpha, \beta \in R, \; 2 \cdot \frac{\langle\beta, \alpha\rangle}{\langle\alpha,\alpha\rangle} \in \mathbb{Z}$

I'm having trouble coming up with examples of such vector subspaces. I tried $R = \{(1,0), (-1,0), (0,1),(0,-1)\}$ where $(a,b)$ is vector (I don't know what other notation to use for a vector since the usual notation is being used by the inner product) but this subspace didn't satisfy the invariant condition.

I actually see that for $n=1$, $R = \{\alpha, - \alpha\}$ works. I think that is it for $n=1$ though.

Can anyone come up with some examples so i can see what is going on?

Comment: It appears that what you're looking for is not examples of vector spaces, but examples of root systems within a vector space.

Comment: Michael, ah you're right. $R$ doesn't contain the zero vector so it isn't a vector space.

Comment: $\ldots\,$and also, $R$ is not closed under addition or under scalar multiplication. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $R$ should have worked, you probably messed up computations. In general, let $\mathcal{B} = (e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ be an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb E$ and put $$R = (e_1,-e_1,\ldots,e_n,-e_n).$$Conditions 1 and 2 are automatic. For 3, we reason as follows: fix $e_i$. We have $$s_{e_i}(\pm e_j) = \pm e_j - 2\frac{\langle  \pm e_j,e_i\rangle}{\langle e_i,e_i\rangle}e_i = \pm e_j \mp 2\delta_{ij}e_i = \begin{cases} \pm e_j \mbox{ if }j\neq i, \\ \mp e_i \mbox{ if }j=i. \end{cases}$$Similarly$$s_{-e_i}(\pm e_j) = \pm e_j - 2\frac{\langle  \pm e_j,-e_i\rangle}{\langle -e_i,-e_i\rangle}(-e_i) = \pm e_j \mp 2\delta_{ij}e_i = \begin{cases} \pm e_j \mbox{ if }j\neq i, \\ \mp e_i \mbox{ if }j=i. \end{cases}$$Condition 4 also follows from the above.

Comment: Ah you are right. I did mess up in my computation. Thank you clearing this up for me!

Comment: No problem, you're welcome

Comment: In fact, once we checked condition 3 for $e_i$, we didn't need to check for $-e_i$, since $(e_i)^\perp = (-e_i)^\perp$. Serves as a reality check, anyways...

Comment: Ivo, what does the $\mp$ mean?

Comment: I'm being lazy and writing two equations in one. As in  $-(\pm  {\rm stuff})=\mp {\rm stuff}$.

Comment: ah okay. And $\delta_{ij}$ denotes the vector $\frac{\langle \pm e_{j}, e_{i} \rangle}{ \langle e_i, e_i\rangle}$

Comment: That fraction is not a vector, it is a number. $\delta_{ij}$ is just the Kronecker delta

Comment: Ivo, When set $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$ for example in a $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ system, does that mean the angle between ANY two vectors in $R$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}$? If the angle between $\alpha_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2}$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}$, great, but then the angle between $s_{\alpha_{1}}(\alpha_{2})$ won't be $\frac{\pi}{3}$. It'll be $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

Comment: No. The angle between $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ is always $\pi$.

Comment: Ivo, again thank you for super quick response. So what does it mean when we set $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$? How does that affect what vectors $R$ consists of?

Comment: I think it is better if you post a new question, I don't know what $\theta$ means for you, and I'm guessing that you're looking at the image of root system in $\Bbb R^2$ by a rotation. In general, if $R$ is a root system in $\Bbb E$ and $T$ is a linear isometry, then $T[R]$ is again a root system. Good luck!

Comment: You're right this deserves a new post. Thanks!